# Cookies not set when nodejs server is not on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have a ReactJS frontend and a NodeJS backend. The frontend calls the login API from NodeJS it returns a cookie with the JWT token which will be used for other calls. I've tested it and it works when both the frontend and backend are running on localhost.

I've used postman and called the same API. One running on localhost and one running on AWS EC2. Both returns the same response, however, the one running on EC2 doesn't set the cookie. set-cookie header is present on both.

I've included the cors configuration.

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: ['http://localhost:3001'],
  credentials: true
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

FOUND THE PROBLEM:

Turns out safari was blocking the cookies. Chrome on iOS is affected by it too. Turning off the option "Prevent cross-site tracking" on safari preferences solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

try to use the full link to send a request to API

```
axios.post('https://mysite/api/v1/login', {email,password,...})
```